# Unstoppable force paradox and reflection of light

Tags: visible-light, momentum, conservation-laws, reflection

Light has momentum and can, therefore, apply a force, however, it is unable to come to rest

However, when light meets a mirror,  it is reflected without a change in velocity

So, therefore is this an example of an unstoppable force meeting an immovable object and what happens when one does -it reflects instantaneously-?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/237638/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Unstoppable force" is not a real thing - forces are not moving objects. Moving objects can apply forces.

When the light meets the mirror, it imparts $2p_{photon}$ of momentum to the mirror, so the mirror does move.

Incidentally, there is also no such thing as an immovable object.